# It is possible do a MYSQL SELECT query to skip some specific value

Tags: php, mysql, subquery, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

Did any possible way to select from table which duplicate value that have specified value, and skip the another one?

I want to select all the record in the table based on below, but only when the same `VALUE` have different `USER` and it was not equal to 0, then skip the specific `VALUE` which `USER` equal to 0, and take the one not equal to 0.

Example Table Data:

```
|----|------------------|--------|
| ID | VALUE            | USER   |
|----|------------------|--------|
| 1  | HELLO WORLD      | 0      | <--- Skip This
|----|------------------|--------|
| 2  | HELLO WORLD 2    | 0      | <--- Take This
|----|------------------|--------|
| 3  | HELLO WORLD      | 5      | <--- Take This
|----|------------------|--------|
| 4  | WELCOME MY WORLD | 0      | <--- Skip This
|----|------------------|--------|
| 5  | WELCOME MY WORLD | 5      | <--- Take This
|----|------------------|--------|
```

Now I am using `SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE (USER = '5' OR USER = '0');`
Then using PHP to filter the VALUE like

```
$newData = array();
foreach($data as $key => $val){
      if($val['USER'] == 5){
            $newData[] = $val;
            unset($data[$key]);
      }
      continue;
}

foreach($data as $key => $val){
      if(in_array($val['VALUE'], array_column($newData, "VALUE"))) continue;
      $newData[] = $val;
}
```

But using this way will lead some problem on pagination with `limit`

Comment: Hello world and hello world 2 are not the same thing so unless you have a rule for saying they are really then it's not possible do you have such a rule?

Comment: I just want to select all record, but only in case the same ```VALUE``` have different ```USER``` and it was not equal to 0, then skip the ```VALUE``` which ```USER``` is equal to 0

Comment: Please edit your question, and include a clear and non-anbiguous explanation of what you want to skip, and based on what exactly, in there directly. This is the main part of your question, so the actual explanation should not be contained only in a comment.

Comment: Sorry about that, I really don't know how to explain my question exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, you can use `not exists` for this. I think the logic you want is:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where 
    user = 5 
    or (
        user = 0 
        and not exists (select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.value = t.value and t1.user = 5)
    )
```

A correlated subquery might be a simpler solution:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where user = (
    select max(t1.user)
    from mytable t1
    where t1.value = t.value and t1.user in (0, 5)
)
```

In MySQL 8.0, you can also use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by value order by user desc) rn
    from mytable
    where user in (0, 5)
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I want, Thank you very much!